# how to copy 3rd party jars in WEB-INF/lib of war

Tags: maven-3

I have created dynamic web project in eclipse.I have developed some code which requires

dependeny jars mentioned in POM as well as some 3rd party jars;so i added all jars in the

build path of the project.these jars are required to compile and run the code when we

deploy in the tomcat.

below pom.xml is used to build the war.I want to include these 3rd party jars in WEB-

INF/lib folder in the war.what changes do i need to make in pom so these jars will come in WEB-INF/lib folder?

Is there any way like whatever jars are added in the project build path does comes in WEB-

INF/lib folder.

or else

put all 3rd party jars in temp folder.then using copy command can we copy these jars from

this temp  folder to WEB-INF/lib folder.what is the best approach?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
  <groupId>com.sample</groupId> 
  <artifactId>SampleWS</artifactId> 
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
  <packaging>war</packaging> 
  <name>Simple CXF project using spring configuration</name>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source> 
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> 
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId> 
      <version>${cxf.version}</version> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Please format your questions better. This is a real pain to read or to improve your question!

Comment: Make those jars whatever they are a real dependencies of your project and they will be packaged into the correct folder.

Comment: you mean say that i need to put all jars as a dependencies in POM?there are so many jars required .so i think its cumbersome to put all as dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add 3rd party jars in WEB-INF/lib folder, no changes needs to be made to POM.xml. Just do the following **Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Click on Add JARs**....locate JARs in your you project's lib folder.. Now these JARs will be added to war along with those in POM.xml.

P.S: Personally i won't recommend to add jars partially from POM and partially from lib folder.

Comment: I am using Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Click on Add External jars.Does thease JARS will be automatically added into WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: @user739115, yes these will be added to project's target(WEB-INF/lib)

Comment: saluja,pom dependency related jars  only coming in WEB-INF/lib.but jars are not coming which are included as external jars in build class path Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Click on Add External jars.

Comment: @user739115, you are right..i am able to use these JARs in my project but not getting these in target folder...